# jQuery: Show span if sibling is active

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```js
if ($("ul li a").hasClass("active")) {
  $(this).next(".info").css("display", "block");
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a>One</a> <span class="info">01</span></li>
  <li><a>Two</a> <span class="info">02</span></li>
  <li><a class="active">Three</a> <span class="info">03</span></li>
  <li><a>Four</a> <span class="info">04</span></li>
</ul>
```

I've simplified my code. Please do not change the logic in general.

The `.info` should be visible if the sibling has the class `.active`. In this case, the `<span class="info">03</span>` should be displayed.

I tried a lot but was not able to find a solution. So I would be very thankful for help! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this using css

```css
a:not(.active) + .info{
  display:none;
}

a.active + .info {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
    <ul>
      <li><a>One</a> <span class="info">01</span></li>
      <li><a>Two</a> <span class="info">02</span></li>
      <li><a class="active">Three</a> <span class="info">03</span></li>
      <li><a>Four</a> <span class="info">04</span></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this purely with a CSS [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator).

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.info {
  display: none;
}

.active + .info {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>One</a> <span class="info">01</span></li>
  <li><a>Two</a> <span class="info">02</span></li>
  <li><a class="active">Three</a> <span class="info">03</span></li>
  <li><a>Four</a> <span class="info">04</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve your problem with the following. Just target the `active` and add your class. You don't really need the if statement here.

```js
$(".active").next(".info").css('display', 'block');
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a>One</a> <span class="info">01</span></li>
  <li><a>Two</a> <span class="info">02</span></li>
  <li><a class="active">Three</a> <span class="info">03</span></li>
  <li><a>Four</a> <span class="info">04</span></li>
</ul>
```